# What is the ".Trash-1000" folder and how to delete it?

Tags: filesystem, delete, trash

Can someone tell me what the `.Trash-1000` folder is and how can I remove/delete it?

It taking up 275 gigs of disk space.

Comment: Can you post the output of this command: ls -ld ~/.Trash-1000

Answer (score 25):

This is the folder of you paperbin.
If you delete something it will not be deleted from disk. It will be moved to this folder instead.

Try to empty the paperbin or delete the folder with the terminal-command as root:

```
sudo rm -rf /path/to/folder/.Trash-1000
```

Comment: This folder contains subfolders "expunged", "files" and "info". What are those used for?

Comment: This may break the "move to trash" function of file browsers if /path/to/folder/ is not writable for UID 1000.  Better remove its contents

Answer (score 16):

GNOMEish file managers need a place to put the trashed files.

- Deleted files on your "home" partition go to:  `/home/username/.local/share/Trash`
- Deleted files on other partitions can't be copied there for performance and space reasons.

So it tries to put them in the `/.Trash-$UID` folder.  Without rw access to that folder, no trash.

Run this bash in the partition root as the user who needs a trash.

```
sudo mkdir .Trash-$UID && sudo chown $USER:$USER .Trash-$UID
```

You can delete this folder and secure the partition / to disable that feature.

```
sudo rm -rf .Trash-xxxx
sodo chown root:root /thepartition
```

Comment: Yes, but it comes back on the next delete.

Comment: After you successfully deleted it, you can then create a file ( not a directory! ) called     .Trash-1000    That will prevent the directory with the same name from being recreated. The empty file will always have size 0

Answer (score 1):

Answers here provide ways to remove the `.Trash-1000` folder itself, but an easier way to make it stop using up space is simply right-clicking on your Trash can and clicking "Empty trash", as the folder simply stores deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot empty your trash, then use this command:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

It will remove trash files recursively.

Comment: Note that this does not remove the file *in* the /files directory but deletes the /files directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep having a trash bin but delete the files that have been moved there and remain on disk, use:

`sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*`

Note in the above that `rm` is the command to remove, and the parameters `-r` means "remove directories and their contents recursively", since by default `rm` doesn't remove directories. The `-f` parameter means "ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt".

At the end of the file path `~/.local/share/Trash/files/*` is the character `*` (...read as "star"), which is a regex term that leads to all files and directories under the `files/"` directory being removed by the command `rm`.

#### Side note

If you'd like to learn more about how to use terminal commands to work with files, the default terminal uses an interpreted programming language called "bash". You can use the type `man rm` within the terminal for more information about the rm command and other common commands.

##### also...

An alternative method for working with directories when you're at an intermediate stage with gnu linux is gnu emacs and its "dired" package.