# How to remove the .Trash-1000 folder from a Samba network volume

Tags: nautilus, samba, trash, nemo, network-drive

This is a follow up on the question [Prevent Nautilus / Nemo from creating `.Trash-1000` folder in mounted devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121039/prevent-nautilus-nemo-from-creating-trash-1000-folder-in-mounted-devices). In essence, the creation of this folder is hard-coded in these programmes and can not be switched off. The wisest thing to do is not use these programmes to access network volumes.

Now I would like to delete the `.Trash-1000` folder Nemo created on a network volume (Samba). It is taking up unnecessary space and confusing other users. However, this what I get when I try to do so:

```
$ rm -rf .Trash-1000/
rm: cannot remove '.Trash-1000/files/n00e005_dem.tif': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '.Trash-1000/files/s50w080_dem.tif': Device or resource busy
rm: cannot remove '.Trash-1000/files/s45e145_dem.tif': Device or resource busy
```

Using `sudo` results in the same messages. How can I remove this folder from the volume?

P.S.: there is [a previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282332/what-is-the-trash-1000-folder-and-how-to-delete-it) on how to delete this folder from a USB volume, but that is a different problem (and straightforward to solve).