# Setting up to use FAT32 USBs

Tags: 18.04, usb, delete, trash

Completely new to Ubuntu.
18.04.4 LTS is installed.

I used a FAT32 USB to add files from my old computer.
The USB now has a (hidden until Ctrl-H) folder called '.Trash-1000' which I cannot delete.
USB name is 'TOSHIBA'.
Username is "a".
Output from 'sudo fdisk -l'

```
 Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        8064 30322687 30314624 14.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

From the little I have determined from other webpages I need to change the permissions to allow the folder to be deleted.

How do I do this? I have no knowledge of Ubuntu command-line code or its use.

Also can the computer be set up so it doesn't create trash folders in USBs? This would seem the most sensible option?
Alternatively can the computer be set up so Trash folders on all USBs can be deleted easily?

TIA

Comment: Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282332/what-is-the-trash-1000-folder-and-how-to-delete-it) and maybe the related links that show up with it.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. Unfortunately I cannot decipher code like /path/to/filename/ and /partition. Do I open a terminal from the TOSHIBA USB or in the Desktop? Is the device "TOSHIBA" or /dev/sdc1, etc?  I understand that drip-feeding information to new people is time consuming and tedious but because this topic continually recurs it may be worth doing a detailed explanation for future reference.

Comment: It sounds like you should learn some basic Linux principles first. It will make your use of Ubuntu much more effective. I'm sure somebody will have a better link handy, but for now maybe https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#1-overview is a good start.

Comment: Great link. Thanks for that.  In the end I just tinkered with my old Windows machine until it fired up and deleted the files there. It only took 20 seconds which is what should happen with Linux systems too!